# One Windows 7 computer gives access denied to one Samba server

Tags: linux-networking, samba, fedora

Our network is  a small peer-to-peer / workgroup, no domain controller, no AD. We just added a new file server running Fedora 27. This server has several shares on it. All shares are accessible from all workstations (Mostly windows 7), except one (also Windows 7). This same problem workstation can access the other Samba servers and shares. The new server is visible in 'Network' on the problem workstation.

I know I have not given enough info. But, I don't know enough to know what to share. Can anyone give me some direction as to where to look for the problem? Let me know what other info I can provide.

Answer (score 1):

When I've had similar issues with Samba, it has been helpful to increase the amount of data that gets logged. I would recommend by starting out with increasing the verbosity of Samba's logs in you **smb.conf** file using the global **log level** or **debug level** options as [documented here](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch12.html).

Next, even though [this article](https://moiristo.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/samba-logging-user-activity/) is a bit old, it may still provide some help tidbits to point you in the correct direction via the use of the Full_audit VFS Module.

Comment: Thanks. I did look at the docs...but missed the log-level setting. I'll give that a  try. btw - default logs don't even show the log in attempt. I think it may be on the workstation side.